# How to combine table and aggregated results in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, union, aggregation

I have a table of indicators (e.g. number of students) for schools in a number of districts.

I need to aggregate those indicators by districts, and I would like to collate those aggregates at the bottom of my initial table:

I have :

```
district    school  students
District1   School1 10
District2   School2 20
District1   School3 30
District2   School4 40
District1   School5 50
District2   School6 60
```

I would like to eventually get in the same table:

```
district    school  students
District1   School1 10
District2   School2 20
District1   School3 30
District2   School4 40
District1   School5 50
District2   School6 60
District1   Total   90
District2   Total   120
```

I have tried

```
SELECT district, school, students
FROM enrolment
UNION 
SELECT district, "Total" as school, sum(students)
FROM enrolment
GROUP BY district;
```

but I'm actually pulling many indicators from many different queries, and aggregating on two additional levels (states and country), so it's very slow. Is there a most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Which RDBMS?  Microsoft SQL Server?  MySQL?  Oracle?

Comment: Having totals in the same table or query does not make sense. Rethink what you really want. Think about it: does having "Total" under the column "school" make sense?

Comment: @NazarMerza It isn't necessarily a bad idea.  That's basically what ROLLUP does...

Comment: Well, yes, because I need to feed the results to existing macros that need that format, and that I don't have access to to modify them

Comment: @BaconBits I'm currently working on Access (although ideally it would work on MySQL because the database will be migrated soon)

Comment: On mySQL you can use WITH ROLLUP after your group by columns. GROUP BY district, school WITH ROLLUP

Comment: I added `MS-Access` tag to your post.

Comment: You might try adding indexes to the columns you are grouping on.  I doubt you are going to find a better performing query than what you are already using (in Access, at least).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL-Server you can use [ROLLUP](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx):

SAMPLE DATA:

```
CREATE TABLE #enrolment(district VARCHAR(25)
                  , school   VARCHAR(25)
                  , students INT);

INSERT INTO #enrolment
VALUES
      ('District1'
     , 'School1'
     , 10),
      ('District2'
     , 'School2'
     , 20),
      ('District1'
     , 'School3'
     , 30),
      ('District2'
     , 'School4'
     , 40),
      ('District1'
     , 'School5'
     , 50),
      ('District2'
     , 'School6'
     , 60);
```

QUERY:

```
SELECT district
    , ISNULL(school, 'Total') AS school
    , SUM(students) AS students
FROM   #enrolment
GROUP BY ROLLUP(district, school);
```

RESULT:

[image]